# Linear regression gives slightly better RMSE than the random forest regression's RMSE

Tags: random-forest

RMSE of Random forest regression : 85.66 RMSE of linear regression : 85.62 I only have five features and around 3800 observations.

I read that most of cases random forest gives better result than linear regression. But I got similar results for these two cases. When does linear regression give slightly better result? What can I exmaine more to find out the reason why linear regression gives slightly better RMSE?

Comment: If your relationship is linear then you can expect linear regression to perform better overall.

Comment: If the relationship is linear, then random forest is more variable than linear regression, which means a slightly larger RMSE but honestly these two metrics are the same for all intents and purposes.  One is not better than another, 1 part in 1000 is random sampling error IMO.

Comment: Is this RMSE in sample or out of sample?